# Docker image file location

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to download a docker image, I installed ubuntu 18.04 and the software required and downloaded the ready made image, my question is that I need to upload two files however I cannot find the folder where i have to upload them to:

docker-compose.yml
launch-virtual-display

when searching for the file nothing relevant is coming up

[search results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSE2M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the docker image to a tar archive. See [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

you can just do, `docker save <image-name>:<tag> > image.tar`.

For your case just do `docker save imatheiam/autoview-bot:latest > autoview-bot.tar`

Comment: thanks managed to do the file changes to the image but got another problem, According to the tutorial I should run the image by using the below command however I am getting an error,  node@f8e64acd5bfb:~/app$ sudo docker-compose up
bash: sudo: command not found
node@f8e64acd5bfb:~/app$ docker-compose up
bash: docker-compose: command not found
node@f8e64acd5bfb:~/app$

Comment: did you install docker-compose? See https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose. Its pretty straight forward. And I wonder why sudo is not installed in your 18.04, Try with full path `/usr/bin/sudo`, if it doesn't work install it `apt-get install sudo` on a root terminal with `su -`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add files to a Docker image, you need to create a custom image based on that image.  The process of doing this is very easy.

Docker has a [good tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  You'll need a Dockerfile, which could be as little as

```
FROM search-results-screenshot
COPY extra-file.txt /opt/search-results-screenshot/static
```

where the "FROM" line names the image you're starting from, the first argument to "COPY" is some file in the same directory as the Dockerfile (or a subdirectory, but not a parent or sibling), and the second argument is some path *inside the image*.  Running `docker build` creates a new image based on this, which you can then `docker run`.

You can't edit an existing image in-place and you can't directly see the contents of an image without launching a container from it.  (Images are *immutable*.)

*Don't be tempted by `docker commit`:* `docker build` is always preferable to it.  In six months when the base image you're using has an important update, or a coworker needs to make some change, if you use `docker build` you can just check out your Dockerfile from source control and re-run it; but if you manually committed an image you need to remember every step that you did and repeat it, by hand, which isn't a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the sudo docker-compose up has to be run from outside the container but from inside the folder since it needs to be in the folder where there is docker-compose.yml as listed in the below tutorial

[Tutorial](https://github.com/IAMtheIAM/autoview-tradingview-chrome-docker-bot)